# How do I save data for a drop-down in a form generation application in CakePHP?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, drop-down-menu

I am using CakePHP and MySQL for my application

I have three tables:

- Forms (id, name, created, modified)
- Attributes (id, form_id, label, type, sequenceno)
- Results (id, form_id, attribute_id, label, value, submitted_by)

The application I am developing is like form Builder.
Generating the fields based on the type (eg .. If type="text" ->generate textbox)

Now I am having a doubt regarding if I my type is "Dropdown" then it will have a dropdown box with some options. How can I keep those choice name?
For example:

```
<select id="jselect">
 <option id="choice1">Male</option>
 <option id="choice2">Female</option>
</select>
```

My sample entry in the table will be like in attributes table

```
       1 1 name text 1
       2 1 age number 2
       3 1 address Textarea 3
```

And in my results table

```
       1 1 1 name aruna 
       2 1 2 age 22
       3 1 3 address XYZ
```

that is how can I save male and female choices in the table? Since I will have the privilege to change the choice name even in between.

Comment: Side note: you may want to include a default_value column in your Attributes table.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using an enum?

[The ENUM Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html)

Comment: I think he wants to *programaticlly* change the possible answers

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want to store the possbile answers for dropdown-type attributes?
Then you have two approches:

- Separate table, holding parent attribute's id and possible value (one per row)
- Field in the attribute table, contaning possible answers as label/value pairs. In this case, you can store in a TEXT column a `serialize()`'d PHP associative array containing `value => label`. It is easier for maintainance and usage in PHP (`unserialize` the field to use it, change it, single `UPDATE` to modify), but you won't be able to is this value properly in a SQL query.

**Edit:** example for solution #2

Add field `answers` of type `TEXT` to your `Attributes` table. Then run this PHP code:

```
// obtain this array programatically:
$genders = array(
    ''     =>    'Unknown',
    'M'    =>    'Male',
    'F'    =>    'Female',
);
// put this into the 'answers' field instead of displaying it
echo serialize( $genders );
```

This will give you an attribute entry like this (which explains why this is hardly query-able):

```
   4 1 gender dropdown 4 a:3:{s:0:"";s:7:"Unknown";s:1:"M";s:4:"Male";s:1:"F";s:6:"Female";}
```

then in your PHP code, just:

```
$genders = unserialize( $my_attribute_row['answers'] );
// here you have your array back
```

Comment: Here is, hope this helps. When you ask for clarity, please specify what you want (like "can you give example on how to do X")